# Check for intersection between 2 dateranges in Postgres

Tags: sql, postgresql

So the idea is very simple :

I have a table containing a `start_date` and `end_date` columns .

I also have 2 parameters (`initial_date`, `final_date`).

I want to check of my daterange `[initital_date, final_date]` has an intersection within any possible combination of the `[start_date, end_date]` daterange.

for example, if I have this following table :

```
id | start_date | end_date 
1   '2022-05-23'  '2022-05-26'
2   '2022-05-25'  '2022-05-30'
3   '2022-05-01'  '2022-05-20'
```

and if `initial_date = 2022-05-19` and `final_date = 2022-05-24`

my desired output would be:

```
id | start_date | end_date 
1   '2022-05-23'  '2022-05-26'
3   '2022-05-01'  '2022-05-20'
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the daterange overlap operator `&&`:

```sql
select *
from my_table
where daterange(start_date, end_date) && daterange('2022-05-19', '2022-05-24')
```

or the standard-compliant `overlaps`:

```sql
select *
from my_table
where (start_date, end_date) overlaps ('2022-05-19', '2022-05-24')
```

Test it in [db<>fiddle.](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_14&fiddle=65106ea099fe6069fd03d9313b1eee2c)

Note. Both of the above solutions assume that each time period represents the half-open interval `start` <= `time` < `end`. In the first variant, you can close the end of the range as follows:

```sql
daterange(start_date, end_date, '[]') && daterange('2022-05-19', '2022-05-23', '[]'),
```

Read in the docs:

- [Range/Multirange Functions and Operators.](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-range.html)
- [Date/Time Functions and Operators.](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/14/functions-datetime.html)

> is it possible to return a true/false boolean if a match is found
> instead of returning rows?

You can do that in an elegant way with a Postgres Boolean aggregate function:

```sql
select bool_or((start_date, end_date) overlaps ('2022-05-19', '2022-05-24'))
from my_table
```

Comment: works like a charm. one more question though, is it possible to return a true/false boolean if a match is found instead of returning rows?


Edit : I guess replacing select * by select count(*)=0 does it!

Comment: overlaps seems to exclude the limit values of daterange. for example if I check for overlaps :
(start_date, end_date) overlaps ('2022-05-19', '2022-05-23')) if does not return the 1st row

Comment: See the note added.